# Rake in Rspec Ruby Does not Work

Tags: ruby, rspec, cmd, rake

I'm having trouble using rake. I'm working on this course that is an intro to rspec.
it first says to install rspec so I enter gem install rspec.

```
     ruby 1.9.3p385 (2013-02-06) [i386-mingw32]

     C:\Users\Edub>gem install rspec
     Successfully installed rspec-2.13.0
     1 gem installed
```

Then I'm supposed to enter the course directory which is cd learn_ruby and then cd 00_hello but mine only works if I enter cd learn_ruby-master\learn_ruby-master\00_hello

```
     C:\Users\Edub>cd learn_ruby-master\learn_ruby-master\00_hello
```

Then I try to use rake like it instructs me to do, and I get some errors. I don't really know what they mean.

```
         C:\Users\Edub\learn_ruby-master\learn_ruby-master\00_hello>rake
         (in C:/Users/Edub/learn_ruby-master/learn_ruby-master)
         You must use ANSICON 1.31 or later (http://adoxa.3eeweb.com/ansicon/) to use         
         col
         our on Windows
         C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in           
          'require': cannot load such file -- hello (LoadError)
         from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_requir
         e.rb:45:in `require'
         from C:/Users/Edub/learn_ruby-master/learn_ruby-master/00_hello/hello_sp
         ec.rb:116:in `<top (required)>'
         from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.13.0/lib/rspec/cor
         e/configuration.rb:819:in `load'
         from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.13.0/lib/rspec/cor
         e/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
         from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.13.0/lib/rspec/cor
         e/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
         from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.13.0/lib/rspec/cor
         e/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
         from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.13.0/lib/rspec/cor
         e/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
         from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.13.0/lib/rspec/cor
         e/runner.rb:80:in `run'
         from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.13.0/lib/rspec/cor
         e/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
         rake aborted!
         C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe -S rspec C:/Users/Edub/learn_ruby-master/learn_ruby-              
         master/00_hello/hello_spec.rb -IC:/Users/Edub/learn_ruby-master/learn_ruby-  
         master/00_hello -IC:/Users/Edub/learn_ruby-master/learn_ruby-   
         master/00_hello/solution -fdocumentation -r ./rspec_config failed

         Tasks: TOP => default => spec
         (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The course then says that an error is supposed to occur and that it supposedly looks like this:

```
      no such file to load -- test-first-teaching/hello/hello (LoadError)
```

Ok, so it then instructs me that I have to define a method in a text editor titled hello.rb
and the code should look like this:

```
    def hello
      "Hello!"
    end
```

So I proceed with the instructions and do all of this in Sublime 2. I title the program in Sublime 2 hello.rb and define the method. This is supposed to fix all the errors but I STILL have the same long error that I did from the start.

Can someone please tell me what is going on here and why rake is aborted. I don't know whats its trying to tell me here. Thanks! If I wasn't specific enough just let me know.

Comment: I had the same problem and bashed my head against a wall for 3 days trying to figure it out. The problem for me was a space in one of my folders to the path. That fixed it. I went through all of the same stuff you went through, a thousand times. [Here is my Stackoverflow question and answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285326/cant-get-rspec-to-work-require-cannot-load-such-file/16285986#16285986)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm very much new to ruby, but the instructions from the book seem off. My understanding is that rake needs to have rake tasks defined in order to work. It's not like the ruby interpreter that you can just do:

```
ruby <ruby_file.rb>
```

And it figures out to interpret the file.

Try checking out this site: http://rake.rubyforge.org/

It gives some intro on creating the rake tasks (which I haven't really done a lot with before; at work other people have written the rake tasks and I just execute them using):

```
rake <task>
```

I hope that gets you started.

Edit:

If you do follow the site instructions I linked, I think in your case you would do something like:

```
task :default => [:test]

task :test do
  ruby "hello.rb"
end
```

And then run it with:

```
rake
```

or

```
rake test
```

The rake default is the task that is run when you don't specify any task (in other words you just run "rake") and in this case it's an alias for the :test task. If you wanted, you could name the :test to something else, but then you'd want to change the default to point to that new symbol.

I also believe rake is a gem. I think it's usually installed by default with Ruby, but if you go to your command line and do:

```
gem query --local
```

and don't see rake there, you'll have to do a `gem install rake` to get it.

Comment: Hmm, where do I type the task in the Text editor along with the method? and it says it has rake and asks me to replace it with gem install rake but I just said no. I'm still kinda confused.

Comment: Ok, I just said Yes to install rake 10.0.3 and now rake is in the query, but the same error still comes up. Ugghhhh

Comment: The Rakefile is its own file - separate from the hello.rb file. I think for simplicity, you could put it in the same directory. So what you would have is a "Rakefile" and a "hello.rb" file in the same directory. Put in what I had for the Rakefile as shown above, and then you should be able, on the command line, to put in: `rake` and it should basically translate to running `ruby hello.rb` and run your ruby file.

Comment: Oh ok that makes a lot of sense I'll try it.

Comment: Ok, I'm new with computers so bear with me. I just want to make sure this is correct. I made two files. One titled hello.rb and ran the code for that. The other one is titled Rakefile.rb and I put the task you gave me in there. This is all in the text editor Sublime Text 2. So i save both of those files into the folder call Ruby Programs. So if I run the rake file in my command prompt it should work? or do i need to save hello.rb and rankfile.rb into the 00_hello file?

Comment: The Rakefile shouldn't have ".rb" at the end. It should just be "Rakefile". You would want to run the rake command in the directory where your Rakefile and hello.rb files exist.

Comment: I think that was the problem I had hello.rb in a completely different file and it was supposed to be in 00_hello. So it now returns C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe hello.rb

Comment: Save the Rakefile as plain text with no extension. You'll know if it works because if you run the rake command, it should spit out the phrase "Hello!" on the command prompt. In your Rakefile file, the definition for the task should be "ruby <path_to_your_hello.rb>" file. So if you had put the Hello definition in the "00_hello" file and put that in the same directory as your Rakefile file, then you would have the task as "ruby 00_hello" without the quotes. Does that make sense?

Comment: Alright sweet I think that fixed it because it now looks like the errors from the example. Thanks a lot man appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome. If you could, please mark the question as answered (vote up too if you feel nice).

Comment: Actually it didn't even need Rankfile because that was already build into the the learn_ruby-master. but its good to know for next time. All I had to do was move hello.rb into the 00_hello file.