# Can't get RSpec to work -- 'require': cannot load such file

Tags: ruby, rspec

I just spent three days of my life banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why a simple 'rake' would not pass my spec file.

If this happens to you:  Do not have a space in any folder path!.  Seriously.  In fact do not have a space in anything you name from here on out.

Here is my console output:

(in `/Users/*****/Desktop/Learning Ruby/learn_ruby`)

```
$ rake
/Users/*******/Desktop/Learning Ruby/learn_ruby/00_hello/hello_spec.rb:116:
  in `require': cannot load such file -- hello (LoadError)
```

Comment: What happens when you just run `rspec`?

Comment: Is this a Rails app? Standalone ruby app?

Comment: It is a ruby app.
When I run rspec it prints out more files locations (that are not in the file location that I'm in for some reason) and the following:

"load': cannot load such file"

Comment: Look this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578575/rspec-kernel-require-rb45in-require-cannot-load-such-file-bowling-rb-l

I think that this will help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The failure is caused by the line: `require "hello"`

This line tells Ruby that it needs to search the load path for a file named `hello.rb`. However, when it looks at the load path, it can't find that file. You should either remove that line and define your code directly in the spec file, or create a `hello.rb` file.

Newer versions of RSpec (2.11+ I believe) automatically add subdirectory `lib` to the load path. Based on your `Rakefile` it seems you are also loading the current lab directory and the subdirectory `solution`.

I'm guessing you're expected to put your solution in `solution/hello.rb`.

Comment: I added the details of my console output with the Rakefile code that was included in the tutorial.

Comment: Ok, that helps. Looks like it found your spec file, but can't find the associated code. Can you paste your spec file? Where is your 'hello.rb' file stored?

Comment: just added the spec file, above.
the 'hello.rb' file is stored in the same file as the 'hello_spec.rb' file.

Comment: I created the 'hello.rb' file and put it both in a 'solutions' folder and outside (and back and forth).  All the same responses on running 'rake'.

Comment: I setup something similar and I get some errors, but rspec does run. I put my file in `solution/hello.rb`. Your `Rakefile` defines `solution` singular.

Comment: Thanks for putting in the time for me.  I appreciate it.

I still haven't been able to get the 'rspec' to work.  I created a 'solution' file with 'hello.rb', moved things around, back, etc...  I even unistalled rvm and ruby and then reinstalled them again.  No dice, unfortunately.  I still get the same console messages as above.  As if 'hello.rb' doesn't exist.

Comment: What is in your `rspec_config` file? That is the only thing I didn't have to look at. Based on this setup, I would say you need to create a `solution` directory in `00_hello`. Place your `hello.rb` file in there. Leave the `hello_spec.rb` file in `00_hello`. Run `rake` from the `00_hello` directory. You will get a failure if your tests don't pass and rake will spit out a stack trace, but you should see rspec run the tests above that.

Comment: Thanks for you continued help, Aaron.  I just figured it out!  Lesson learned:  never name a folder using a space.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was changing the require statement to a require_relative

I am using windows and an IDE